# JSON : Select Radio button base on response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

How I could populate the checked state of radio buttons depending on data loaded from the database?

I want to get data radio button for this form

```
                  <div class="col-md-4">

                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="menu_status" class="flat-red" value="1"> Enable
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="menu_status" class="flat-red" value="0"> Disable
                    </label>
```

this my array result

```
{"menu_id":"00001","parent_id":"0    ","menu_name":"Dashboard","menu_title":"Dashboard","url":"dashboard_c","position_menu":"1","parent_status":"0","menu_status":"1","fa_icon":"fa-dashboard","type":"1"}
```

and I am pass that result through ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('cpanel/form_c/data_edit/')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        $('[name="menu_id"]').val(data.id);
        $('[name="parent_id"]').val(data.parent_id);
        $('[name="menu_name"]').val(data.menu_name);
        $('[name="menu_title"]').val(data.menu_title);
        $('[name="url"]').val(data.url);
        $('[name="order"]').val(data.position_menu);
        $('[name="parent_status"]').val(data.parent_status);
        //$('[name="menu_status"]').val(data.menu_status);
        $('[name="fa_icon"]').val(data.fa_icon);
        $('[name="type_form"]').val(data.type);

        $.each (data, function (i, obj) {
          $(':radio[name="menu_status"][value=' + obj.menu_status + ']').prop('checked', true);
        });


        /*if (data.parent_status===1) {
          $('[name="menu_status"]').val("1").prop('checked',true);
        } else {
          $('[name="menu_status"]').val("0").prop('checked',true);
        }*/

        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit Menu'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

    },
```

Can someone help me to take the json data to select the appropriate choices?

Comment: my problem is no 3, I can't make radio button selected

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {"menu_id":"00001","parent_id":"0    ","menu_name":"Dashboard","menu_title":"Dashboard","url":"dashboard_c","position_menu":"1","parent_status":"0","menu_status":"1","fa_icon":"fa-dashboard","type":"1"}

console.log(data.menu_status)
$('input[name=menu_status][value='+data.menu_status+']').prop('checked', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="menu_status" class="flat-red" value="1">Enable
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="menu_status" class="flat-red" value="0">Disable
  </label>
</div>
```

try this way, the check radio button will be equal to what `data.menu_status` value is

Comment: I tried this before but still did'nt get the result I want. But radio button is still not checked

Comment: can you see in the demo it is that enable is checked because the value is 1 if value is 0 then it will be disable maybe the value of `data.menu_status` is not 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the radio button class is **flat-red**. You could simply use this one instead of going with complex selectors.

You could use a condition instead.

```
if (data.parent_status == 1) {
     $('.flat-red').checked = true;
}
```